# How to drop rows from a dataframe as per null values in a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to drop rows from a dataframe as per null values in a specific column?

Say I have a dataframe that has three columns a,b,c and all can have null values, but I only want to droprows where column b has null/NaN. How can I do that in pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['b'], axis=1)
```